# nHibernate count rows in subquery

Tags: nhibernate, count, subquery

How can I do something like this in nHibernate:

```
select count(*)
from (subquery)
```

It is a rather simple query in SQL, but the solution is not so obvious in nHibernate. An obvious solution would be something along the line of:

```
    var rowcount = Session.QueryOver<Entity>()
       .Select(Projections.Alias(Projections.Count(Projections.SubQuery(detachedQuery)), "count"))
        .FutureValue<int>();
```

However, this results in an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747718/nhibernate-queryover-get-a-row-count-with-group-by-in-a-subquery) SO answer doesn't work for me, as I have a more complex grouping.
My question originates from [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012966/torowcountquery-seems-to-ignore-groupings) where I tried to use `ToRowCountQuery`, but that function strips groupings form the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an old post by Ayende which gave me a solution ([Counting paged data](http://ayende.com/blog/2334/paged-data-count-with-nhibernate-the-really-easy-way)).

I created my own dialect as described in that post and added the `rowcount` function to my paged query. And presto, I got my rowcount in a single query to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `session`, you could

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(....)

int count = (int) criteria.UniqueResult();
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116188/how-do-i-select-the-count-of-an-nhibernate-subquerys-results for more info. It is couple of years old, but hope it helps.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure how that would work. Where do I put my subquery? The related SO answer doesn't use a subquery, but just provides an alternative solution, which also works in that particular case. The Criteria-solution seems to be similar to my QueryOver solution which results in an exception. Next to that, I would prefer a solution using QueryOver.